# CircuitPython passing a Tuple as an argument, error expects Integer

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, oop, adafruit-circuitpython

I'm building a basic daylight alarm clock out of a rp2040, RTC, and NeoPixel strip. I'm building the Class for Alarm objects that contain: Time to trigger(hour, minute, second), Function to trigger, and Args for the function being triggered, this is the relevant slice of code:

```
    class Alarm(Clock):
    def __init__(self, time, trigger, *args):
        self.absolute_alarm = super().calculate_absolute_time(time)
        self.trigger = trigger
        self.args = args
    def trigger_alarm(self):
        self.trigger(*self.args)
```

and in the main code.py *This is line #61 that is throwing the error*:

```
wake_up_alarm = Alarm((7,0,0), light_bar_soft_fade, 1, pixels_60)
```

Absolute time is just the time in seconds since midnight, makes it easier than trying to juggle hour/minute across 12hr time. Clock is a NeoPixel inherited class that just contains some posting functionality, thats all working as expected. When I run this code I get this error:

```
code.py output:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "code.py", line 61, in <module>
TypeError: can't convert tuple to int
```

I've narrowed it down to throwing on the tuple object, but I can't see where Python thinks it needs to be an int? How can I correct this?

The full class code isn't too long so just in case:

```
import time
import neopixel
class Clock(neopixel.NeoPixel):
    def __init__(self, pin, n, *, bpp=3, brightness=1.0, auto_write=True, pixel_order=None, debugging=False):
        super().__init__(
            pin, n, bpp=bpp, brightness=brightness, auto_write=auto_write, pixel_order=pixel_order
        )
        if len(self.byteorder) == 3: self.fill((0,0,0))
        if len(self.byteorder) == 4: self.fill((0,0,0,0))
        self.last_minute = self.last_hour = self.last_second = 0
        self.clock_face = self.alarms = []
        self.show()
    def post(self, t):
        self.clock_face = []
        for each in range(0, 12): self.clock_face.append([0, 0, 0, 0])
        self.clock_face[t.tm_hour % 12][0] = 1
        self.clock_face[int(t.tm_min/5)][2] = 1
        for each in range(0, 12): self[each] = self.clock_face[each]
        self.show()
        for alarm in self.alarms:
            if calculate_absolute_time(t) == alarm.absolute_alarm: alarm.trigger()
    def calculate_absolute_time(self, time):
        try:
            absolute_time = (time.tm_hour * 60 + time.tm_min) * 60 + time.tm_sec
        except AttributeError:
            absolute_time = (time[0] * 60 + time[1]) * 60 + time[2]
        return absolute_time
```

**MINIMAL REPRODUCABLE CODE**

```
import neopixel
import board
class Clock(neopixel.NeoPixel):
    def __init__(
        self, pin, n, *, bpp=3, brightness=1.0, auto_write=True, pixel_order=None, debugging=False,):
        super().__init__(pin, n, bpp=bpp, brightness=brightness, auto_write=auto_write, pixel_order=pixel_order,)
    def calculate_absolute_time(self, time):
        return True

class Alarm(Clock):
    def __init__(self, time, trigger, *args):
        pass
def light_bar_soft_fade(*args):
    pass

clock_pixels = Clock(board.D10, 12, brightness=1, auto_write=False,
                           pixel_order=(1, 0, 2, 3))
wake_up_alarm = Alarm((7,0,0), light_bar_soft_fade, 1, clock_pixels)
```

New error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "code.py", line 18, in <module>
TypeError: can't convert tuple to int
```

Comment: Tuples don't have attributes named `tm_hour` et al. `Clock.calculate_absolute_time` appears to expect something like a named tuple or (most likely) a value of type [`time.struct_time`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html?highlight=clock#time.struct_time).

Comment: Thats why I included the except AttributeError: so that I could pass either RTC structured time or [hr,min,sec] lists. Not to mention the error is thrown on __init__ from code.py not calculate_absolute_time from clock.py

Comment: What happens if you pass an actual `struct_time` value to `calculate_absolute_time`?  I would make that function less flexible, and require the caller. Please try to produce a [mcve]; there is no (obvious) line 61 in your code, so it's not clear that the error is where you think it is.

Comment: This is line #61: ```wake_up_alarm = Alarm((7,0,0), light_bar_soft_fade, 1, pixels_60)```

Comment: What function `calculate_absolute_time` is being called from `Clock.post`? It's not `Clock.calculate_absolute_time`.

Comment: Please don't post excerpts from your code. What appears in the question should be runnable, as is, to reproduce the error. That's not the case here. If there is code in the question that can be removed and without interfering with producing that error, remove it.

Comment: I have edited the post to remove everything but what causes the error, including all the functionality of calculate_absolute_time

Comment: Does `Clock` override `__new__`? If not, line 18 in your minimal example should be a no-op, as `Clock.__init__` never gets called. Which is to say, I think `Clock.__new__` is receiving `(7,0,0)` as an argument and assuming it's intended to be used for `pin`.

Comment: You figured it out, thank you! I'm not sure what a no-op is, but I added an empty \_\_new\_\_ call and passed it the correct arguments. Sorry for all the confusion.

Comment: No-op = no operation = doesn't do anything.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you're passing a tuple like an argument to calculate_absolute_time(time), but your method calculate_absolute_time needs to receive an int.

I guess you should set the type of every args in methods and etc. For example:

class Clock:
def **init**(self):
... etc ...

```
def calculate_absolute_time(self, time:tuple[int]) -> float:
    ... code ... 
    return float()
```

With something like this, you'll able to know what's wrong and where's the bug.

For more, I'd need to get more details about your code. I hope I helped you. Good lock.

Comment: I guess my post wasn't clear enough, the code never gets to ```calculate_absolute_time``` it throws an error in initialization, this is line #61: ```wake_up_alarm = Alarm((7,0,0), light_bar_soft_fade, 1, pixels_60)```

Comment: I've edited the main post to a minimal reproducible error, only 18 lines